# Activity Indicator on a button click in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a button of submitting form data to the service. When user click it it submit data and give alert of success. I want to add activity indicator in it , when user click button of submit the time it takes to submit the data the activity indicator should move and than hide when it data is submitted.I'm confused where should i use it in the code , I'm confused at that whether it shall be call after response or anywhere else. My code is,

```
 NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"propertyfor=%@&propertytype=%@&landarea=%@&country=%@&city=%@&price=%@&description=%@&location=%@&name=%@&email=%@&phone=%@",_propertyfor,_propertytype,_landarea,_country,_city,_price,_propdes,_propdescrip,self.name.text,self.email.text,phone];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"My URL"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
}] resume];
```

Comment: load the indicator right after the button click and hide it after you get the data i.e in the block after requestReply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     **//Start Activity Indicator here.**
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"propertyfor=%@&propertytype=%@&landarea=%@&country=%@&city=%@&price=%@&description=%@&location=%@&name=%@&email=%@&phone=%@",_propertyfor,_propertytype,_landarea,_country,_city,_price,_propdes,_propdescrip,self.name.text,self.email.text,phone];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"My URL"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
     **//Stop Activity Indicator here.**
        NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
    }] resume];
```

Comment: It wil adjust the time itself? @Abhishek Jain

Comment: how can we hide this before clciking the button ? . @Abhishek Jain

Comment: We should show it right after button click and Hide it when we got the response.

Comment: But it is seen on the screen before click. How i can hide it. @Abhisekh Jain

Comment: Can you share the full code where you are showing and hiding the indicator?

Comment: Thanks got it.I have one question can its size be increased? Abhishek Jain

Comment: Yes , use UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start animating before session created and stop animating one you get reply. In your code :

```
     .
     .
     .
     .
    [activity startAnimating];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [activity stopAnimating];
       });
        NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
    }] resume];
```

Comment: It wil adjust the time itself? @sschunara

Comment: how can we hide this before clciking the button ? .@sschunara

Comment: @HamzaImran Yes it will adjust time itself. You need to keep activity indicator hidden while showing/animating. first make activity.hidden= false; then start animating and hide once stop animating is called. U can also select that option in storyboard to make it hide when it's not animating.

Answer (score 0):

Replace followind code with original:

```
CGSize s1 = UIApplication.sharedApplication.windows[0].frame.size;
CGRect r1 = CGRectMake(s1.width/2-20, s1.height/2-20, 40, 40);
UIActivityIndicatorView *act = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:r1];
[self.view addSubview:act];
[act startAnimating];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
    [act stopAnimating];
    [act removeFromSuperview];
}] resume];
```

Comment: what's the point of calling start and stop animating method consecutively ?

Comment: every time event is trigger then need to start Animinating

Comment: this doesn't work, the spinner gets removed and user can't even see it!

Comment: how i can hide it before click on a button , it is visible on a screen. @Sakir Shesrasiya